# Azure Microsoft Translate Text, Long Input results in HTTP 414

Tags: azure, translate, microsoft-translator

**Problem: Microsoft Translate Returns HTTP 414 on long text translate requests**

**Question:** Is there a way around this to limit errors?

**Background**

I am attempting to translate several paragraphs of text at a time via Microsoft Translate Text API in the new Azure cloud via this API http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate. The API seems to only support sending text via http `GET` and a query param `?text=`. Typically I would expect to be able to accomplish this via the body of a POST, however the API only seems to support GET. There is a `TranslateArray` POST but it still takes `texts` via query param according to testing / swagger.

The API docs specify a 10,000 character limit but I am frequently getting `HTTP 414 Request-URI Too Long` error responses on sizes smaller than that, I'm assuming due to the long URL which also includes a JWT token.

I am looking for a way around this to reduce my error rate to Microsoft Translate.

I have considered segmenting the text into multiple chunks, but without a good tokenizer in the native language I think I risk breaking up context / meaning and distorting the translation.

Comment: A URL can have a maximum length of about 2000 characters usually so that can't go to 10,000.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware many browsers have limits, but this is being accomplished via code and I've read about higher limits such as 8192 in Apache. I'm not sure how Microsoft implemented their server but the query parameter has the below in their docs for "text" which contributes to source of my confusion if there is no way to send text in the body. 
**"REQUIRED. A string representing the text to translate. The size of the text must not exceed ten thousand characters."**

Answer (score 0):

Translator API supports POST where the text(or texts) are in the body.  See the [Example for TranslateArray](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_TranslateArray)

There the example is:

```
<TranslateArrayRequest>
  <AppId />
  <From>language-code</From>
  <Options>
    <Category xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</Category>
    <ContentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">text/plain</ContentType>
    <ReservedFlags xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" />
    <State xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >int-value</State>
    <Uri xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</Uri>
    <User xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</User>
  </Options>
  <Texts>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">string-value</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">string-value</string>
  </Texts>
  <To>language-code</To>
</TranslateArrayRequest>
```